# Can't add library in imported cordova project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I imported a Cordova project but I can't add any library.
Here are two screenshots: http://s27.postimg.org/d1p8wjdbn/file2.jpg

http://s29.postimg.org/7qrc8m8jb/file1.jpg

The CordovaLib folder isn't in the project because it disappeared after I added the gen folder as a source folder, I don't know why this happens. Anyways, I can't add the library even if I import CordovaLib in the project.